# How to write when "is" is pronounced like apostrophe one?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Here's what the protagonist in a movie said (I'm typing what I heard, may or may not be grammatically correct): "Balls in your court".

In that phrase, the term 'balls' is shortened version of "Ball is..."

What I don't understand is that how do I write a grammatically correct sentence which has a shortened version of "Ball is in your court" that sounds like "Balls in your court"?

Is it "Ball's in your court" OR "Balls in your court" (as I mentioned above) OR is it something else?

I'm skeptical about "Ball's in your court" because that apostrophe would imply that it's about something related to the ball; it just feels out of place.

I hope the question is clear otherwise let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Apostrophes are also used to indicate contractions.

Comment: @Xanne Oh, I get it. You may consider posting that as an answer. I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ball's in your court.

's is used to mean 
1. possession (or) is 
2. short for is/has/does/us.

(Reference for the second meaning - google 
is.
"it's raining"
has.
"she's gone"
us.
pronoun: 's
"let's go"
does.
"what's he do?"

More examples: 
Apple's not good - Apple is not good
Apple's quality is not good - The quality of apple is referred to here.

Answer (score 2):

"Ball's in your court" is what you heard. It's short for "the ball is in your court" meaning that it's up to you to make the next move.

Comment: You can strengthen this answer by explaining that it is a *contraction*.